# on('change') with window.open() don't work on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

When I try to make a redirection in a new window on Android / Desktop it's working fine but on iOS it simply doesn't work. Probably the same security as video autoplay. Did someone found a trick to make it work on iOS ?

**HTML**

```
<select id="boo">
    <option>--- Choose url ---</option>
    <option data-url="http://google.com">Google.com</option>
    <option data-url="http://facebook.com">Facebook.com</option>
    <option data-url="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo.com</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('#boo').on('change',function(){
        var url = $(this).find('option:selected').data('url');
        window.open(url);
    });
});
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/warface/1owmtcey/

**Note**

The result must absolutly open a new window/tab in the browser. `_self` isn't an option.

Comment: Are you including the JS externally or the JS code is in same file?

Comment: @Varun Code is working fine on other platforms so the JS file is loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling **window.open()** try setting **window.location**.

```
$(function(){
    $('#boo').on('change',function(){
        var url = $(this).find('option:selected').data('url');
        window.location = url;
    });
});
```

Tested on iOS 8.4, working as expected.

Comment: It works yeah since it's not a `_blank` page but I need a `_blank` page so can't accept your answer.

Comment: You _could_ create a new anchor element and trigger a click event on it, but I'd imagine you would get a blocked popup, same as **window.open()**.

Comment: we use window.open to open new tabs... otherwise we would use window.location .. this is not a "clean " solution...